# Google Analytics - Events

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I am running a website with 'Universal analytics' from Google.

I am implementing a code - onClick="ga('register', 'Signup', 'Outgoing links', 'Website Name', 'advert');" for the button ()

I have done this three days ago and I still do not see an Event under Behavior -> Events -> Overview

Am I doing anything wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

thanks!

Nagaraj

Comment: Wrong syntax, look up here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to in the comment, the syntax is incorrect. For UA, the syntax should be:

```
onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'your_category', 'your_action', 'your_label');"
```